# Can I verify a message with Openssl if it was sign with .Net System.Security.Cryptography?

Tags: hash-signature

Sorry, this is sort of a beginner question.

But providing that it is possible to find the same options, can I verify a message with Openssl if it was sign with .Net System.Security.Cryptography ?

Let's say I need to do this for sha1, are the underlying algorithms similar enough to be able to verify the signature of another implementation ?

And if it's works, should I rely on that ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your question is valid and touches upon an essential principle in cryptography: interoperability.

In theory, cryptographic algorithms, such as SHA-1, are standardized, meaning their implementations should produce the same results regardless of the platform (e.g., OpenSSL in a Linux environment vs. System.Security.Cryptography in .NET).

**Example:** If you have a message `"Hello World"`, and you sign this message using a private key in .NET's `System.Security.Cryptography`, then you should be able to verify the signature of this message using the corresponding public key in OpenSSL, provided that both platforms use the standard `SHA-1` for signing and verifying.

However, there are a few considerations:

1. **Padding & Encoding:** Different platforms might handle padding and encoding differently. This is especially important for signature schemes. Ensure that both platforms use the same padding scheme (e.g., `PKCS#1 v1.5`).
2. **Key Formats:** Make sure the private and public keys are in compatible formats. For instance, .NET might use a different key format than OpenSSL, so you might need to convert one format to another for them to be interoperable.
3. **Deprecation of SHA-1:** It's important to note that SHA-1 is considered deprecated for many cryptographic applications, including digital signatures, due to vulnerabilities that allow for collision attacks. It would be advisable to use a more secure hash function, such as `SHA-256`.
4. **Relying on Interoperability:** While it is technically possible to verify a signature from one platform on another, whether you should rely on this for a production system depends on the criticality of your application and thorough testing. It's essential to conduct comprehensive tests, considering various edge cases, before deciding to rely on such a setup.

In conclusion, while it is possible to achieve what you're aiming for, it requires careful implementation and thorough testing to ensure reliability and security. Always prioritize using updated and secure algorithms and practices in cryptographic operations.